# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'server' of undefined

Tags: signalr

I'm trying to leverage SignalR while developing Chrome Extensions. I can run [sample](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) successfully but when I try to change the client from webpage to chrome extesion, I got some trouble. I define the connection the same as the sample like below:

```
var chat = $.connection.myHub;

console.log("start connect");
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
  // Call the Send method on the hub. 
  console.log("Test");
  //chat.server.send("extension", "start");
  chat.server.send("succ");
 });
```

But I always get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'server' of undefined`.

I have already enabled CrossDomain in my server side. Since `chat.server' is invoked, it seems the connection is established successfully. Did I miss adding some files/scripts in my extension folder?

Comment: is /signalr/hubs executed and does it contain "myHub"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not bringing in the `/signalr/hubs` file.  The auto-generated hubs file is what adds the `.server` and the `.client` properties to the connection object.  Therefore if you're correctly including the `/signalr/hubs` file the next step is to ensure that your hub is being included in the dynamically generated JS file.

Comment: You are right, seems I failed to add this `/signalr/hubs` file. When I use background page, I can include `http://mysite/signalr/hubs/` easily. But if I just use `background.js` to do all the logic, how can I load `/signalr/hubs`? seems it's not a single js file.

Comment: I think you'd be better just using the raw hubs API.  Checkout the samples here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#nogenconnection

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem is that C# automatically change the first letter of Hub name and methods to lower case in hub.js. **MyHub1** changes to **myHub1** and **Hello()** changed to **hello()** in client side automatically.

if you have:

```
public class MyHub1 : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        
    }
}
```

in your Hub.

in client side it must be used like this:

```
var simpleHubProxy = $.connection.myHub1;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log("Connected.");
    simpleHubProxy.server.hello();
});
```