# How to use signalr in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to use signalr in my chrome extensions but I keep getting

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined'
```

Now I know I need to use a script

```
<script src="http://localhost:3600/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

like this, but i can't figure out where and how to use it in chrome extensions.

My manifest file looks like this

```
"manifest_version": 2,    
  "name": "Jquery Tests",
  "description": "This extension tests jquery.",
  "version": "1.0",       
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },    
    "content_scripts":
    [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js", "popup.js"]
        }
    ],    

  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "background",
    "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],    
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
```

and here is my popup.js where I get the error

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    debugger;
    console.log('jquery working in content!');
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:3360/signalr";
    $.connection.logging = true;
    var ticker = $.connection.notificationHub;
    //var ticker = $.connection.tempratureMonitorHub;

    //signalr method for push server message to client
    ticker.client.notify = function (message) {
        console.log("Notification added!");
        if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
            updateNotificationCount();
        }
    }
});
[][1]
```

Comment: Please check solution given in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596964/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-server-of-undefined) and also the given API [guide](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome extensions , the dynamically created proxy i.e **hubs** file is unavailable as files are loaded once per installation.
This file contains information of *client* and *server*. To include this information in your extension you need to follow the following steps as mentioned in [this link](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy)

1. Install the **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils** NuGet package.
2. Open a command prompt and browse to the tools folder that contains
   the SignalR.exe file. The tools folder is at the following location:

   [your solution
   folder]\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils.2.1.0\tools
3. Enter the following command:

   ```
   signalr ghp /path:[path to the .dll that contains your Hub class]

   The path to your .dll is typically the bin folder in your project
   folder.
   ```

   This command creates a file named server.js in the same folder as
   signalr.exe.
4. Put the ***server.js*** file in an appropriate folder in your project,
       rename it as appropriate for your application, and add a reference
       to it in place of the "signalr/hubs" reference.